# How do you put your own rules into .htaccess?

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

Is it possible to put your own rules in .htaccess but still give WordPress control over 'it's bit'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default. WordPress will add markers before and after its rules and not touch anything else:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# WP rules here …
# END WordPress
```

Just make sure to set your rules before the WordPress rules, because WordPress’ rewrite rules are rather greedy (they have to), so later rules will probably not apply.